# Excel: Pivot Table Filter Macro Error If Data already Filtered

Tags: vba, excel, pivot

I have a macro assigned to a button which is meant to filter data by bottom 10 and it works except that if the data is already filtered when the button is pressed again, I get an error "Application-defined or object-defined error".

How can I prevent this? The filter is part of a pivot table. I have the same macro but for a top 10

The macro I'm using is the following.

```
Sub TopTenByQty()

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTopBottom").PivotFields("Name"). _
    PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlBottomCount, DataField:=ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTopBottom").PivotFields("Quantity"), Value1:=10

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found a way to work around the error by adding an additional line to reset the filter before it filters the data, that way whenever the button is pressed, it resets and filters the data again. Now I'm able to have the top10 button and buttom10 button and can run it without any problems. This is what the macro looks like now.

```
Sub TopTenByQty()

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTopBottom").PivotFields("Name"). _
    ClearAllFilters

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTopBottom").PivotFields("Name"). _
PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlBottomCount, DataField:=ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
"PivotTopBottom").PivotFields("Quantity"), Value1:=10

End Sub
```